# Is Zuul/Ribbon/Eureka combo ideal for edge services

Tags: security, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, netflix-ribbon

`Eureka` is ideal for `middle tier services` as `service registry and discovery` soln. 
Isn't it going to be a security smell, if the *same* `eureka server` is used to register `edge services` also? 
In such case, is it advisable to have separate `eureka servers` for `edge` and `middle services`?

Comment: What would be the security gain if you put each category of your services in a different registry? How will your edge services discover the "middle" services?

Comment: @HannounYassir Bang On! Absolutely correct!. I tried hosting 2 different eureka server at 2 different Tomcat deployments in local and then connecting the `App Service(s)` to one `eureka server` and the `Zuul (i.e. App Client)` to another `eureka server`. The `eureka-client.properties` within the `eureka server` specified the `defaultZone`, that had both eureka servers.. When I hit the `Zuul` proxy Url, it still gets routed to correct `App Service`. So even when `edge service` works as a `client`, they should still be able to discover `middle service` and thus no `security` gain.

Comment: Also, if I consider this article ("https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/netflix-shares-cloud-load-balancing-and-failover-tool-eureka-c10647ef95e5") the section "When should I use Eureka", then it seems like `Zuul` is probably not best suited using `ribbon-eureka` as a client for `edge services`, for avoiding any security smells?